# How to loop through a multiarray in PHP with a needle?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 32
            [addition] => 
            [year_min] => 14
            [year_max] => 999
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 16
            [addition] => 1
            [year_min] => 8
            [year_max] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 8
            [addition] => 1
            [year_min] => 3
            [year_max] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price] => 0
            [addition] => 
            [year_min] => 0
            [year_max] => 2
        )

)
```

I also have a user's age.

I want to programmatically find the price and addition the user belongs to, but I can't figure how to do it. I know it might be very simple, but well, not for me right now :-)

Can anyone push me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: `if (age < yearMax and age > yearMin)`

Comment: Have you tried `foreach()` through the array and seeing if the age is in the range `year_min` and `year_max`?

Comment: Are you wanting to return the array elements that the age falls in between the year_min and year_max?

Comment: @Torben, Is there is one and only one returned result every time or could there be more than one result that would match the age passed in?

Comment: Yes, for each age there will always be only one returned result. And Yes, it would be great to return the array element that the age fald in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$age = 42;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['year_min'] <= $age && $age <= $item['year_max']) {
        print_r($item);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if he is wanting all matches, but your solution will only give him the first record it finds.

Comment: According to provided array - there will be only one match.

Comment: Correct, but that is probably a sample sub-set. I will ask him on the question if there is one and only one returned result and what is expected if there is more than one.

Comment: Tried it and it works perfect for my problem. Awesome and thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution.

```
$age = 4;
$found = array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($age){
  return $age >= $item['year_min'] && $age <= $item['year_max'];
});

print_r($found);
```

Comment: Looking at the context of the question, it looks as though the idea is to find the price for a person of a certain age.  This would generally lead to 1 record, otherwise you have 1 person with a range of prices - although if this does happen, I would choose the cheapest :)

Comment: @NigelRen, agree, but I think it is best to return all possibilities and then determine if the result set is more than one what to do with the result. Unless you know for sure that there is always one result, I always program in a way to reduce error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try all the solutions when I return to my laptop :-)